# Given $\rm V=J/C$, is it better to think of the Coulombs as moving charge, or moving electrons?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electrons, charge, voltage

I have been confused by how voltage is measured in joules per coulomb, until I thought of it in the context that the coulombs aren't measuring charge, but instead are measuring how many electrons are being moved. Is this a correct conculsion?

Comment: Electrons are not the only charge carrier.

Comment: [_Coulomb_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb) is the SI unit of [_charge_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge). In electronic circuits electrons normally are the only mobile charge carriers, but other species can also carry charge. E.g., in electrochemistry, electric currents can be due to the movement of [positive or negative ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion), and physicists talk about the current in a particle accelerator beam when that beam could be made of protons or heavy ions or other charged particles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not a correct conclusion. You almost never need to know the sign of the charge carriers. The only place that comes into effect classically is if you are doing a cathode ray tube or the Hall effect. Otherwise current is the flow of charge. If you are thinking about electrons otherwise then you are confusing yourself. Plus, if your circuit includes a battery then electrons are not the only charge carrier in your circuit, and some will be positive. So assuming that the charge carriers are all electrons is often wrong.

In this case voltage is joules per coulomb, where the coulomb is a measure of the charge moved, independently of what type of charge carriers are used.

Comment: By "charge moved", do you mean the movement of charge carriers from one place to another?

Comment: Yes, the charge is moved from a place with one voltage to a place with a different voltage. The change in the energy is the change in voltage times the charge moved.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.